# Excel VBA working with Styles

Tags: excel, vba, styles

Maybe a simple solution to this question.
Im trying to create VBA code in excel, so it will Move Cells Highlighted in "Good" from Sheet A to Sheet B.

I can do move cells with no issues, add styles, but need help on the above, if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check if a `Cell`'s `.Style = "Good"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub OutOfStyle()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
        If cel.Style = "Good" Then
            cel.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(cel.Address)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Adapt this to your own worksheet names.

Comment: Thanks, its doing what I want it to do, just to figure a few other bits.

Comment: in sheet 1 i have rows filled in style as in Good, bad, the code does copy and paste the good cells in its current position, how can i alter the code so it paste on sheet 2 on the next free cell, A row of cells would be highlighted in Good, which what i want to cut nd paste to sheet 2

Comment: @halo_4  I don't understand

Comment: So in Sheet 1, I have a dataset, the rows of the dataset would be Style of "Good" or "Bad".  but the dataset will be mixed of the two cell Styles. and on Sheet 2 would only have data that is "Good", while the code does paste the required cells and changing the .Copy to .Cut is what i want it to do, the code pastes the cells where it came from, data on sheet 2 is forever growing dataset, so i need it do cut the row and paste to sheet 2 on the next free row, i have tired to edit my existing code which does already :- Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Row Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)